# Order by clause with Union in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, union

I want List of party names with 1st option as 'All' from database. but i won't insert 'All' to Database, needs only retrieve time. so, I wrote this query.

```
Select 0 PartyId, 'All' Name
Union
select PartyId, Name
from PartyMst
```

This is my Result

```
0   All
1   SHIV ELECTRONICS
2   AAKASH & CO.
3   SHAH & CO.
```

when I use `order by Name` it displays below result.

```
2   AAKASH & CO.
0   All
3   SHAH & CO.
1   SHIV ELECTRONICS
```

But, I want 1st Option as 'All' and then list of Parties in Sorted order.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to use a sub-query with `CASE` in `ORDER BY` clause like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  Select 0 PartyId, 'All' Name
  Union
  select PartyId, Name
  from PartyMst
) tbl
ORDER BY CASE WHEN PartyId = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
,Name
```

Output:

| PARTYID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | All |
| 2 | AAKASH & CO. |
| 3 | SHAH & CO. |
| 1 | SHIV ELECTRONICS |

See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6d3c2/1)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are anyway hardcoding 0, All just add a space before the All

```
Select 0 PartyId, ' All' Name
Union
select PartyId, Name
from PartyMst
ORDER BY Name
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fdfca/8)

Raj

Comment: I tried on both 2008 R2 and 2012. It works even in SQL Fiddle link I posted. No idea why it does not work for you. Anyway, the response posted by @hims056 is better.

Comment: It displaying write answer by checking it in fiddle.
but not in sql server 2008..
I also wondered..

Comment: As commented earlier also, for me it works in SQL Server also.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'order by' with the top instrucction in a union in this way:

```
Select 0 PartyId, 'All' Name
Union
select * from ( 
  select top (select count(*) from PartyMst) PartyId, Name
  from PartyMst
  order by Name
)
```